# trying to create timer for quiz

Tags: javascript, php

```
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    myTimer()
}, 1000);
var d = 1;
function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d++;
}
```

Can any one help me how to set the dynamic timer in `JavaScript`?

I'm trying to create a quiz application and I need to run a timer for the questions which is already available in the database.

I have to retrieve a time from the database and I have to run a count-down timer.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What is the actual problem? We're not supposed to write all the code for  this?

Comment: the problem is i don't no how to set the timer dynamically ?

Comment: You've got a time value from the DB. Set another variable to that value, then decrement by one in `myTimer`, and when `0` is reached, [clear the interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval). To get the interval ID, see [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: Firstly using javascript to set a timer for a quiz would be inefficient as it can be altered by using the console.It would be better to use PHP script to start the timer based on timestamp and submit form if the time exceeds

Comment: can you please tell how to split this 00:20:15 into separate hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myTimer(d) {
  d++;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
  return d;
}

var d = 1;

var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  d = myTimer(d);
}, 1000);
```

like this?

[Edit after reading comments:]

```
var endpoint = [php_timestamp_here];
var countdown = setInterval(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var ts = d.getTime();
  if( ts >= endpoint ){
    // stuff after reach the point...
    clearInterval(countdown);
  }
  // stuff every second
}, 1000);
```

Comment: may i know where to set the retrieved time from the database ??

Comment: I don't know what you like to achive. In fact your code just count a number up to space (endless).

Comment: i would like to show countdown timer for online quiz, the time is already set i have to retrieve that and set to the timer, if the time gets over the  form should be auto submitted.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp Just have a look to system time. But remember, everyone in the world can have a diffrent time than your server system time. Just get your stop time as timestamp and take the current system timestamp as start time. Then count starttime-1 every second till you reach the stop time.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this. It doesn't reply on the timer being perfect.

```js
var running = false;
var timeToRun = 10000;  // 10 seconds
var startTime;
var timer;
var output = document.getElementById("output");


function start(){
    running = true;
    startTime = new Date();
    timer = setInterval(check, 100);
    output.innerHTML = "Started<br>" + output.innerHTML;
}

function stop(){
    running = false;
    clearInterval(timer);
}

function check(){
    var now = new Date();
    var left =  (startTime - now) + timeToRun;
    output.innerHTML = left + "<br>" + output.innerHTML; 

    if (left < 0){
        stop();
        output.innerHTML = "times up <br>" + output.innerHTML; 
    }
} 

start();
```

```html
<div id="output">o</div>
```

Comment: maybe change this code. Enter a "endpoint" instead of a "timeToRun". That is what @Sandhiya would like to have :)

Comment: $set_maxtime = 00:20:15; this is retrieved from the database and assigned to one variable, where to add this and if this time gets over means, i have to alert an user like test going end by 2 min